# Which Ananasi Book is Complete?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

I've recently joined a group of people playing Werewolf the Apocalypse and I'd like to create an Ananasi character. However it seems to be difficult to work out which book is the right one to get. As far as I can tell there are a couple of options:

- The Ananasi 'breed book' ([like this one](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/12/Ananasi?it=1))
- The Players Guide to the Changing Breeds book ([this one](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/3364/Players-Guide-to-the-Changing-Breeds?it=1))
- The 20th Anniversary (W20) Changing Breeds book ([this one](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/121087/W20-Changing-Breeds))

Which of these (or another if I've got it wrong) has the most comprehensive and complete set of rules and information for playing Ananasi characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third one — [Changing Breeds](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/121087/W20-Changing-Breeds) – is the most recent of the three, and is compatible with the 20th Anniversary rules for **Werewolf: the Apocalypse**. It's going to include some information from the *Ananasi* breedbook (including updated gifts) and supersede the Player's Guide to the Changing Breeds, which came out for *Werewolf Revised.* If you were going to choose one of the three, go with that one. By not buying the breedbook, you'll mainly lose out on fiction, art, sample characters, and older Gifts and Rites that may not have been converted.

As @Discord notes, you'll still need a copy of the *Werewolf* core rules, as the book refers to it rather than reproducing repeated mechanics.

Answer (score 4):

The Players Guide to the Changing Breeds provides basic information on the Ananasi. It covers their forms, Gifts, etc. It provides enough information to create an Ananasi PC or NPC. However, it is a rough overview of the Breed, rather than an in-depth study.

If you want more detail on their history, mindset, etc, then you'd want to pick up the Breed Book. It will give additional Gifts, Traits and Fetishes, as well as several sample Ananasi characters.

(I cannot recall right now if the Breed Book has the complete rules to play them. I seem to remember that it still refers back to The Players Guide for some of the info. At least, that's the way it was in previous editions.)

Comment: Any gift that is duplicated from the W:tA book is makes reference to it.

Comment: Players Guide to the Changing Breeds is... in many respects a very flawed cutdown of the Breedbooks for Revised. W20 Changing Breeds is much higher quality in *that* regard.

Answer (score 1):

The Breedbook is going to have the most information, but also is the oldest.

The Players Guide does update from 2nd Edition to Revised (3rd) edition.

W20 updates to the recently released edition.

(Of all the Breedbooks, only Nuwisha required access to the Player's Guide.)

Answer (score 0):

The different books contradict each other quite a lot when it comes to the Ananasi, and all of them lack essential information. I would go with the latest one (W20 - Changing Breeds) for the rules, and Breedbook Ananasi for the fluff.
However, make sure to check out the Ananasi article at White Wolf Wikia, and especially the companion articles about errata and clarifications and the Crawlerling form.